# SwiftUI GridRow background

Tags: swiftui, grid

Is there a way to set the background of an entire `GridRow` inside a `Grid`?

The code below sets the background of each individual cell, but I would like to set the background of the row regardless of the spacing between the cells.  Notice the gap between columns 1 and 2.  Such a feature is useful in showing selecting an entire row in a grid table.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Grid {
            GridRow {
                Text("Column 1")
                Text("Column 2")
            }
            GridRow {
                Text("Row 1 value 1")
                Text("Row 1 value 2")
            }
            GridRow {
                Text("Row 2 value 1")
                Text("Row 2 value 2")
            }
            .background(Color.red)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: After further research I don't believe there is a way, except to use `horizontalSpacing` of 0 between columns, and use padding between individual Texts.

Answer (score 1):

when I was doing a title row (across 4 columns), I used a ZStack.  You might be able to repurpose it for your use case:

```
GridRow {
    ZStack {
        Color.gray.gridCellUnsizedAxes([.horizontal, .vertical])
        HStack {
            Text("Full row").font(.headline).foregroundStyle(.white).padding()
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "arrow.up.forward.circle").padding(.trailing)
        }
    }
    .cornerRadius(10)
    .gridCellColumns(4)
}
.padding(.top)
```